# Double Tap Button issue when keyBoard opens React native

Tags: react-native, keyboard-events

I know there are already so many queries on this topic, I have tried every step but still won't be able to fix the issue.

Here is the code :

```
    render() {
    const {sContainer, sSearchBar} = styles;

    if (this.props.InviteState.objectForDeleteList){
      this.updateList(this.props.InviteState.objectForDeleteList);
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <CustomNavBar
          onBackPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
        <View
          style={sContainer}
        >
          <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
            <TextInput
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              placeholder={'Search'}
              placeholderTextColor={'white'}
              selectionColor={Color.colorPrimaryDark}
              style={sSearchBar}
              onChangeText={(searchTerm) => this.setState({searchTerm})}
            />
          </ScrollView>
          {this.renderInviteUserList()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

renderInviteUserList() {
    if (this.props.InviteState.inviteUsers.length > 0) {
      return (
        <SearchableFlatlist
          searchProperty={'fullName'}
          searchTerm={this.state.searchTerm}
          data={this.props.InviteState.inviteUsers}
          containerStyle={styles.listStyle}
          renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyListContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.noUserFoundText}>
          {this.props.InviteState.noInviteUserFound}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }


renderItem(item) {
    return (
      this.state.userData && this.state.userData.id !== item.id
        ?
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.itemContainer}
          onPress={() => this.onSelectUser(item)}>
          <View style={styles.itemSubContainer}>
            <Avatar
              medium
              rounded
              source={
                item.imageUrl === ''
                  ? require('../../assets/user_image.png')
                  : {uri: item.imageUrl}
              }
              onPress={() => console.log('Works!')}
              activeOpacity={0.7}
            />
            <View style={styles.userNameContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.userNameText} numberOfLines={1}>
                {item.fullName}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <CustomButton
              style={{
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                marginTop: 10,
                marginBottom: 10,
                width: 90,
              }}
              showIcon={false}
              btnText={'Add'}
              onPress={() => this.onClickSendInvitation(item)}
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity> : null
    );

  }
```

**I even tried with bellow code as suggested by @Nirmalsinh **:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" style={sContainer}>
        <CustomNavBar
          onBackPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        />
        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          placeholder={'Search'}
          placeholderTextColor={'white'}
          selectionColor={Color.colorPrimaryDark}
          style={sSearchBar}
          onChangeText={(searchTerm) => this.setState({searchTerm})} />
        {this.renderInviteUserList()}
      </ScrollView>
```

**I have followed this article**:

> https://medium.com/react-native-training/todays-react-native-tip-keyboard-issues-in-scrollview-8cfbeb92995b

I have tried with **keyboardShouldPersistTaps=handled** also but still, I have to tap twice on my Custom Button to perform an action. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong inside the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` in a ScrollView or Scrollables like FlatList SectionList etc.  and embed a TouchableWithoutFeedBack to handle the case for dismiss on outside clicks.

```js
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
 <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
   // Rest of the content.
 </ScrollView/>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

For FlatList and SectionList you will have to handle `KeyBoard.dismiss` separately.

Comment: Upvoted...Check the docs for the difference between "always" and "handled". For me, "handled" works a lot better. "The keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by a [child like a button press]."

Comment: What if I don't want a Scrollview?

Answer (score 10):

You need to add give value **always** in **keyboardShouldPersistTaps** to allow user tap without closing the keyboard.

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
```

For example:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
 // Put your component
</ScrollView>
```

NOTE: Kindly put your tappable component inside the ScrollView. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Hi @Nirmalsinh, Already there: <View
          style={sContainer}
        >
          <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
            <TextInput
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              placeholder={'Search'}
              placeholderTextColor={'white'}
              selectionColor={Color.colorPrimaryDark}
              style={sSearchBar}
              onChangeText={(searchTerm) => this.setState({searchTerm})}
            />
          </ScrollView>
          {this.renderInviteUserList()}
        </View>

Comment: Where you put your button code? Is it inside the scrollview?

Comment: No, it's not inside the scrollview, I just put searchbox inside scrollview

Comment: Thats a issue. We need to keep all component inside the scrollview to get the event.

Comment: <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
          <View style={sContainer}>
            <TextInput
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              placeholder={'Search'}
              placeholderTextColor={'white'}
              selectionColor={Color.colorPrimaryDark}
              style={sSearchBar}
              onChangeText={(searchTerm) => this.setState({searchTerm})}
            />
            {this.renderInviteUserList()}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>

Comment: Correct. Try with it.

Comment: this.renderInviteUserList() will contain SearchableFlatlist and inside this I have renderItem function which contains the button component inside it, So by placing this.renderInviteUserList() inside scrollview the whole component will be under scrollview automatically

Comment: <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
Replace with       < ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer} keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">

Comment: Your main container is View and you are using scrollview for Textinput. And there is not any another compoenet. So make your main component Scrollview and add property into it.

Comment: same issue , i have to press my button two times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185774/discussion-between-siddharth-and-nirmalsinh).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please try this, It's working for me, it will works you also, i hope it helps...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).