# Pressing a button only dismisses the keyboard

Tags: react-native, button, keyboard, modal-dialog

I have a `Modal` which contains a `TextInput` and a `Button`. When the modal is opened, the keyboard appears which enables to enter text in the TextInput.

My problem is that when I press the button for the first time, the keyboard is dismissed but the button `onPress` method is not triggered.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Modal,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  InteractionManager,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';

import theme from '../../styles/theme.style';

import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import I18n from '../../utils/i18n';

class RenameDrillModal extends React.Component {
  // Enables to open the keyboard when the component is rendered
  inputRef = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.focusInputWithKeyboard();
  }

  focusInputWithKeyboard() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.inputRef.current.focus();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Modal
          animationType="fade"
          transparent
          visible
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.props.close();
          }}
        >
          {/* The sole purpose of the three following tags (TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, TouchableWithoutFeedback) is to close the modal when clicking outside of it */}
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={1}
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
            onPressOut={() => {
              this.props.close();
            }}
          >
            <ScrollView directionalLockEnabled>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                <View style={styles.modalTitleView}>
                  <Text style={styles.modalTitleText}>{`${this.props.drillTitle}`}</Text>

                  <View style={{ minWidth: '50%', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <TextInput
                      style={{ minWidth: '90%', margin: 5, marginBottom: 0, flex: 1 }}
                      placeholder={I18n.t('drillEditor.drillManager.clickHereToRename')}
                      onChangeText={text => this.props.textModified(text)}
                      ref={this.inputRef}
                    />

                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                      name="check"
                      color={theme.COLOR_PRIMARY}
                      size={26}
                      onPress={() => {
                        console.log('Rename, onPress called');
                        this.props.close();
                        this.props.confirmNewName();
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </ScrollView>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalTitleView: {
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  modalTitleText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: theme.BACKGROUND_COLOR_LIGHT,
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 8,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default RenameDrillModal;
```

The second press on the button works but do you know how I could both dismiss the keyboard and push the button by only pressing once?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928562/5532513

Comment: Oh yes perfect! Sorry I did not find it before posting.